# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist when building docker file for an ASP.NET Core API application

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, file-not-found, dotnet-restore

I am trying to build a docker image for an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application and I fail to restore the packages. My solution has multiple projects and after copying all the project files, I am trying to create a layer which contains restored dependencies only.

#### The docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj", "ExampleApi/ExampleApi/"]
COPY ["Common.Web/Common.Web.csproj", "ExampleApi/Common.Web/"]
COPY ["Example.Data/Example.Data.csproj", "ExampleApi/Example.Data/"]
COPY ["Example.Services/Example.Services.csproj", "ExampleApi/Example.Services/"]

RUN mkdir /tmp/build/
COPY . /tmp/build
RUN find /tmp/build -name *.csproj

RUN dotnet restore "ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj" --verbosity detailed
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ExampleApi/ExampleApi"
RUN dotnet build "ExampleApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ExampleApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ExampleApi.dll"]
```

#### Docker build

I am running without cache to be able to output all the csproj files within the container for each run (otherwise it gets cached and the files are not longer displayed).

```
docker build --no-cache -f ExampleApi/Dockerfile .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  116.4MB
Step 1/22 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
 ---> a843e0fbe833
Step 2/22 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in e33e9c821c0b
Removing intermediate container e33e9c821c0b
 ---> eec973a226e0
Step 3/22 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Running in 8e813a3a8b85
Removing intermediate container 8e813a3a8b85
 ---> c8d95a3a1de4
Step 4/22 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
 ---> cef7866e800b
Step 5/22 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in f56bf9402ed1
Removing intermediate container f56bf9402ed1
 ---> 55694332db0e
Step 6/22 : COPY ["ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj", "ExampleApi/ExampleApi/"]
 ---> 4beb2e169ec7
Step 7/22 : COPY ["Common.Web/Common.Web.csproj", "ExampleApi/Common.Web/"]
 ---> ed7a9c81e8f7
Step 8/22 : COPY ["Example.Data/Example.Data.csproj", "ExampleApi/Example.Data/"]
 ---> aaca52c111b4
Step 9/22 : COPY ["Example.Services/Example.Services.csproj", "ExampleApi/Example.Services/"]
 ---> efb15c17a096
Step 10/22 : RUN mkdir /tmp/build/
 ---> Running in 7da9eae324ca
Removing intermediate container 7da9eae324ca
 ---> b06126b19a7f
Step 11/22 : COPY . /tmp/build
 ---> 04598eaab98c
Step 12/22 : RUN find /tmp/build -name *.csproj
 ---> Running in 2fd26dba963d
/tmp/build/ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.Data/Example.Data.csproj
/tmp/build/Common.Web/Common.Web.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.Sql/Example.!Sql.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.Services/Example.Services.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.Services.Tests/Example.Services.Tests.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.IdentityServer.Infrastructure/Example.IdentityServer.Infrastructure.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.IdentityServer/Example.IdentityServer.csproj
/tmp/build/Example.Data.Tests/Example.Data.Tests.csproj
/tmp/build/ExampleIntegrationApi/ExampleIntegrationApi.csproj
Removing intermediate container 2fd26dba963d
 ---> 78eadf796305
Step 13/22 : RUN dotnet restore "ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj" --verbosity detailed
 ---> Running in 5dc9b5bbd04e
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj" --verbosity detailed' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

`find` indicates that `ExampleApi/ExampleApi.csproj` is there, yet the `dotnet restore` complains about not finding it.

Comment: You possibly need `WORKDIR /tmp/build` before the `RUN dotnet restore`, although it looks like you ought to be in /src and the restore should work there too?

Comment: @Rup - `tmp/build` was a temporary copy to hold my context (folders and files). I replaced that with a simple find (`RUN find . -name *.csproj`) and realized that the folders had an extra level. Thanks for hint that helped me figure out what was wrong.

Comment: @Alexei-checkCodidact I am facing exactly the same issue and not able to resolve this. I have the following Solution structure "Source/webApp.sln" 
"Source/src/projone/projoneapi.csproj","Source/src/projtwo/projtwo.csproj" . I have my docker file in Source/folder where solution resides. 
running the dir command reveals the projoneapi.csproj exists in copy command but while restoring it complaints that file does not exists. 

Can you help me how you solved the issue?

Comment: @Alexei-checkCodidact were you able to figure this out?